# App removed from PlayStore because of library not in the project

Tags: android, gradle

I received an email from Play Store stating that:

*We found that your app is using Tencent TBS SDK which contains code to download executable code (e.g. dex, JAR, .so files) from a source other than Google Play.*

We never intended to use this library, in fact it doesn't show up in the dependencies tree (./gradlew app:dependencies), but after we package the APK few references appear in the following files:

```
app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexMerger/xxx/release/0/classes2.dex
app/build/intermediates/transforms/proguard/xxx/release/0.jar
app/build/outputs/mapping/xxx/release/seeds.txt
app/build/outputs/mapping/xxx/release/mapping.txt
app/build/outputs/mapping/xxx/release/usage.txt
app/build/outputs/mapping/xxx/release/resources.txt
```

how do I find out which dependency is using this library? I tried to exclude it in gradle but nothing happens.

Comment: Run a Gradle dependency report (`dependencies` task for your module).

Comment: I did try that as the first thing, it's usually the best way to find out nested dependencies. Unfortunately that library didn't show up in the tree. The signature appeared only in the dex files. I explained it better in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately I didn't find a clean way to find the library mentioned by the Play Store support.
Every time I compiled the project, I would find the methods signature in the dex file.
So I went for the empirical way:

- Created an empty project with all of the gradle dependencies + modules
- Compiled the project while commenting few of the dependencies out
- When the dex file didn't reference the library I was looking for, I knew I had found the culprit

Couple of notes:

- the Play Store must've added this check in the last few weeks, since I had been using this library for the past 2 years.
- The sources of the found dependency didn't mention in their signature that library

Comment: Out of curiosity, what was the dependency that was causing the issue?

Comment: It was a Rich Text Editor that I had found a couple of years ago: https://github.com/mr5/icarus-android . Apparently it references com.tencent.* that has been banned on the Play Store because includes the possibility to load jars outside the store.

Comment: what is the way to resolve it? ALso what have you used the lib instead of this ? Please help me out

Comment: I removed the library and replaced it with a simple TextArea, didn't really have time to dig into it any further. My answer goes in detail about how I resolved it.

Comment: Hi! I tried this exact same approach, but I could not find any references to tencent in the .DEX file. Anything I might be missing here?

Comment: did the playstore mention the Tencent TBS Library?

Answer (score 1):

I was working on flutter project, facing the same issue, but found that **flutter_filereader** was the package which was creating issue.

I simple removed this package to resolve the problem.

Comment: so did you ever get an alternative file reader? or you wrote yours from scratch?