# app is not getting deployed because of generation of dex/jar files from using Tencent SDK

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, deployment

```html
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number is used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
# In Windows, build-name is used as the major, minor, and patch parts
# of the product and file versions while build-number is used as the build suffix.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.18.2 <3.0.0'

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  # cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  http: ^0.13.5
  # circle_nav_bar:
  responsive_bottom_bar: ^0.0.4
  # device_info: ^0.4.0+4
  # device_id: ^0.2.0
  uni_links: ^0.5.1
  circular_check_box: ^1.0.4
  roundcheckbox: ^2.0.5
  auto_size_text: ^3.0.0
  otp_text_field: ^1.1.3
  pinput: ^2.2.20
  flutter_otp_text_field: ^1.1.1
  custom_check_box: ^0.0.4
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.15
  flutter_screenutil: ^5.6.0
  scan: ^1.6.0
  images_picker: ^1.2.11
  permission_handler: ^10.2.0
  qr_code_scanner: ^1.0.1
  # local_auth: ^1.1.9
  uuid: ^3.0.6
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.11.0
  file_picker: 
  image_picker: ^0.8.6
  geolocator: ^9.0.2
  open_file_plus: ^3.3.0
  file_preview: ^1.1.4
  flutter_file_view: ^2.1.3
  # flutter_localizations:
  dropdown_search: ^5.0.5
    # sdk: flutter
  pdf_render: ^1.3.6
  flutter_cache_manager: ^3.3.0
  searchable_dropdown: ^1.1.3
  
  flutter_slidable: ^0.6.0
  searchfield: ^0.7.4
  pdf: ^2.1.0
  path_provider:
  dio: ^4.0.6
  circle_nav_bar: ^2.0.1+1
  # fluentui_icons: ^1.0.0
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
  local_auth: ^1.1.9
  youtube_player_flutter: ^8.1.2
  show_up_animation: ^2.0.0
  # open_file: 


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter



  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  
  


flutter_icons:
    android: true
    ios: true
    image_path: "assets/app_icon_wo_bg.png"

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/
    # - assets/icon1.png
    # - assets/Login.gif
  

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  fonts:
    - family: Poppins Medium
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Poppins-Medium.ttf

    - family: Montserrat
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Montserrat-VariableFont_wght.ttf
          
        
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

After a recent review, we found that your app  is not compliant with one or more of our Developer Program in Policies See below for more information about your app's status and how to correct the

Issue with your app

We found that your app is using Tencent TBS SDK which contains code to download executable code

(eg dex, JAR sofies) from a source other than Google Play

If necessary, you can consult your SDK provider(s) for further information

i tried to rerun the build once again and also add the app in a new project but wasnt able to pin point which certain package is actually creating the issue with the application

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70409916/6561930

Comment: thank you for the reply but that hasnt helped me can u please tell me how to see through my gradle dependencies in the application

Comment: You may be using a plugin made by Tencent, which is not supported by PlayStore, can you provide your pubspec.yaml ?

Comment: Have added please do check this out once.