# Google Play Flutter app rejected Tencent TBS SDK

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, flutter-dependencies

Im experiencing a rejection by Google Play for my Flutter app.

The issue:
*We found that your app is using Tencent TBS SDK which contains code to download executable code (e.g. dex, JAR, .so files) from a source other than Google Play.*

I have gone through all my dependencies to check if there is any link with Tencent TBS SDK but I cannot find anything.

Below you can find the list of dependencies used in my Flutter app's pubspec.yaml

Does anyone know what package could be causing this? Or how to resolve this issue?

```
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.6
  connectivity_plus: ^2.1.0
  provider: ^6.0.1
  progress_indicators: ^1.0.0
  http:
  path_provider: ^2.0.8
  image_picker: ^0.8.4+4
  onesignal_flutter: ^3.5.1
  rounded_loading_button: ^2.1.0
  get_it: ^7.2.0
  holding_gesture: ^1.1.0
  package_info_plus: ^4.0.2
  flutter_inappwebview: ^5.7.2+3
  flutter_treeview: ^1.0.7+1
  url_launcher: ^6.1.11
  dropdown_button2: ^1.7.2
  device_info_plus: ^9.0.2
  flutter_localizations:
      sdk: flutter
  intl: ^0.18.0
  image_cropper: ^5.0.0
  flutter_html: ^3.0.0-beta.2
  get: ^4.6.5## Heading ##
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.10.0
```

The iOS version of the app was successfully submitted to the Apple Store.

Many thanks!

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61210998/app-removed-from-playstore-because-of-library-not-in-the-project

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I already tried this approach. I searched the DEX file in the APK for any references to tencent but I could not find them.

Comment: can you post your app level build.gradle file? android/app/build.grade.

Comment: Hello! I resolved the problem. It was an oversight on my end. Apparently when sending the prod changes to review on the play store, an older version of the app in a diferent phase (closed testing) got flagged instead of my prod version. However this was not very clearly reported so I misunderstood the message from google play store. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @TNelen i am getting same issue, still not able to resolved it, can you tell me what step should i follow?